# PySimpleGUI, how to get string to print on new line instead of cutting it off?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I was working on an image viewer, but I noticed in the image viewer when the link to be displayed is too long it cuts it off. How can I modify this code So that if the string is too long, it prints it on a new line instead. I was following a guide so you can take a look at https://realpython.com/pysimplegui-python/

```
# img_viewer.py


import PySimpleGUI as sg

import os.path


# First the window layout in 2 columns


file_list_column = [

    [

        sg.Text("Image Folder"),

        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-FOLDER-"),

        sg.FolderBrowse(),

    ],

    [

        sg.Listbox(

            values=[], enable_events=True, size=(40, 20), key="-FILE LIST-"

        )

    ],

]


# For now will only show the name of the file that was chosen

image_viewer_column = [

    [sg.Text("Choose an image from list on left:")],

    [sg.Text(size=(40, 1), key="-TOUT-")],

    [sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],

]


# ----- Full layout -----

layout = [

    [

        sg.Column(file_list_column),

        sg.VSeperator(),

        sg.Column(image_viewer_column),

    ]

]


window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout)


# Run the Event Loop

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:

        break

    # Folder name was filled in, make a list of files in the folder

    if event == "-FOLDER-":

        folder = values["-FOLDER-"]

        try:

            # Get list of files in folder

            file_list = os.listdir(folder)

        except:

            file_list = []


        fnames = [

            f

            for f in file_list

            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))

            and f.lower().endswith((".png", ".gif"))

        ]

        window["-FILE LIST-"].update(fnames)

    elif event == "-FILE LIST-":  # A file was chosen from the listbox

        try:

            filename = os.path.join(

                values["-FOLDER-"], values["-FILE LIST-"][0]

            )

            window["-TOUT-"].update(filename)

            window["-IMAGE-"].update(filename=filename)


        except:

            pass


window.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

To me, it's better to use library `textwrap` to **fill** your text into new text with new line `'\n'` before assign to `sg.Text`. Set `size` to `(40, None)`, `40` is the wraplength.

You'll have a nice string as output, could be nicer than a list ;)

Example here:

```py
import textwrap
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

text = (
    "The mission of the Python Software Foundation is to promote, protect, "
    "and advance the Python programming language, and to support and "
    "facilitate the growth of a diverse and international "
    "community of Python programmers.")

new_text = textwrap.fill(text, 40)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Line", size=(40, None), key="OUT")],
    [sg.Button("Update1"), sg.Button("Update2")],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event == 'Update1':
        window['OUT'].update(new_text)
    elif event == 'Update2':
        window['OUT'].update("Line")
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```